# Override a defined CI/CD variable in a gitlab job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

i am currently facing an issue using Gitlab-ci. i am using gitlab 13.12 community edition.
I want to be able to override the value of a CICD variable from within a gitlab-ci.yml job.

you might say that i could just pass out the value from one job to another but the goal is to change that value so that , on the next pipeline , all my jobs will use the updated one.

To be precise , i want to be able to change MY_CICD_VARIABLE_TO_CHANGE that i've defined in project > cicd > variables. and update this value from a gitlab-ci job

something like this but not only change it for the current pipeline but update it :

```
change_variable_value:
  stage: "change_variable"
  image: myimage
  script:
    - $MY_CICD_VARIABLE_TO_CHANGE="value_changed"
```

, i tried to do every single solutions specify here :
https://docs.gitlab.com/13.12/ee/ci/variables/index.html#override-a-defined-cicd-variable

nothing seems to work.
I also tried to use artefact but it seems that i am not able to pass artefact between 2 distinct pipelines, they have to be part of the same pipeline , even by curling the api (at least in the community edition)

Any idea is more than welcome :)

Comment: Are you triggering the next pipeline from this pipeline? Or do you just mean the next pipeline to run, whenever it might be?

Comment: There is an API method to [update a project variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html#update-variable); did you try that?

Comment: i also recommend to add what is your usecase. i do not think what you plan to do is a good practice. Each pipeline is executed on its own. So if you want to edit a CI Variable, you need the API or manipulate a file and commit this. Either way, i do not think it is advisable without the use case :)

Comment: Hi , thanks a lot for your answers ! actually my use case is that i want to run my job twice. the first run set my custom variable to "true" according to a rule condition. And i would like to be able to run the job  a second time  with a rule condition only if the variable set before is at "true". So as a consequence, being able to save this value and use it in the second run. but since they are not part of the same pipeline the variable is either empty or set to value i attributed to it before the job changes it

Comment: if you want to run a job twice, why not define it twice in the CI YAML but where the second job only runs if the variable matches a specific value?

Comment: for within the same pipeline (either default, or with [needs](https://docs.gitlab.com/13.12/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#needs)), you can use [artifacts:reports:dotenv](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/artifacts_reports.html#artifactsreportsdotenv)